# why my scrapy always tell me “TCP connection timed out” in Scrapinghub but working fine in my local Machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, python-requests

I am getting following error in app.scrapinghub.com but working fine in my local machine.

Note: I am using requests module in python(Scrapy framework) to send request and using BeautifulSoup to parse response

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1297, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError: TCP connection timed out: 110: Connection timed out.
```

Example Code:

```
from scrapy.spider import Spider
import requests,json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta 
from Scrapy_Project.pipelines import MySQLPipeline

class exampleSpider(Spider):
name='test'
start_urls=['http://www.example.com']
custom_settings = {
    'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
        'Scrapy_Project.pipelines.MySQLPipeline': None
}
}

def parse(self, response):
    current_date=datetime.today()
    today=current_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

    tommrrow_date= current_date+timedelta(days=1)
    tommrrow=tommrrow_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

    date_list=[today,tommrrow]
    data_lists=[]
    for date in date_list:
        m_show_time=[]
        url='http://www.example.com?id=123'
        page = requests.get(url) ///
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        movie_list=soup.find_all('exampe_info')
        for index, item in enumerate(data_lists):
            name=item.find('title').get_text()
            x_time=item.find('starttime').get_text()
            result= {'name': name ,'show_date':date}
            yield result
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Pitto I edited my question with example above...is this helpful?

Comment: Could firewalls exist between your machine and example.com? Or is there a connection page for `http://www.example.com?id=123`

Comment: @Serge Ballesta I just specify  http://www.example.com?id=123 in this exampe only.I have different real url in my code which is working from postman as well as in my local machine but problem is only in app.scrapinghub.com

Comment: @Krishnajoshi: I did assume that example.com was a fake URL. My question should read: *is there a firewall or a login page for access to your real URL?*

Comment: @SergeBallesta Nope...there is no any login page for access to URL..I can directly get response from browser or postman without any security

Comment: @Krishnajoshi: a browser usually sets a number of headers. Some sites refuse to give back a response if they thing that the request was forget by a program instead of being sent from a browser. Use developper tools from you browser to read *exactly* how the request was build, then try to mimic it in Python. But as you do not describe precise symptoms, this is just a wild guess...